# Possible bug in Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The integral I'm considering is:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{\pm t\theta}}{4\sinh^2\left(\frac{s+ i\theta}{2}\right)} = 2\pi e^{\mp s}\Theta(\pm s)$

for $s\neq 0$ (otherwise there some other subtleties). For the case $e^{i\theta}$, using assumptions ($s>0$ or $s<0$), Mathematica gives the right answer, i.e. $0$ or $2\pi e^{-s}$, but the opposite case i.e. with $e^{-i\theta}$, it gives zero in both cases which is wrong. Interestingly, if you put in actual numerical values for $s$, then it'll give the right answer again.

Correct answer:

```
Integrate[E^(I θ)/(
 4 Sinh[(s + I θ)/2]^2), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
 Assumptions -> s > 0]
(* 2 E^-s π *)

Integrate[E^(I θ)/(
 4 Sinh[(s + I θ)/2]^2), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
 Assumptions -> s < 0]
(* 0 *)
```

Incorrect answer:

```
Integrate[E^(-I θ)/(
 4 Sinh[(s + I θ)/2]^2), {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
 Assumptions -> s < 0]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: Please provide the Mathematica code that you have used.

Comment: The integrand in the LaTeX version is not the same as the integrand in the Mathematica version.  Putting this aside, it does appear that this is a bug.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Indeed, sorry about that. I corrected it.

Comment: I suggest that you wait for additional responses until 24 hours after your original post.  Then, if no one has explained this issue, add the bug tag and label, and report the issue to Wolfram, Inc.  By the way, what version of Mathematica and operating system are you using?  I reproduced the error with 10.4.1 and 11.0 under Windows 10, 64x.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I am on Windows 10 64x and Mathematica 11.0.
By the way, I have a new bug of the same spirit, which is some sense even worse because for actual parameter values it still gives the wrong answer (the answer has the wrong sign). Should I do a new post for that?

Comment: Yes, please do.